# RecyclerView with CardView is laging and not scrolls smoothly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Trying to load around 500 rows of data in recycler view, but it is lagging while scrolling.

Data doesn't include any kind of images, it is just plain text. Thus could not find any reason of laging.

The xml and java code used is as follows:-

xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/markeListCard"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_150sdp">


    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_125sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/compltedtlist"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="School Name :"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:textColor="#0E9CE0"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:id="@+id/scndprsnname" >
            </TextView>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Divisional Public School"
                android:ems="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:id="@+id/scholnametxt" >
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="District :"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:textColor="#0E9CE0"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:id="@+id/detaildadresedit" >
            </TextView>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_38sdp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Aleem Ahmed"
                android:ems="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:id="@+id/tehsilname" >
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_48sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="Tehsil :"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:textColor="#0E9CE0"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:id="@+id/pcname" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_45sdp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Lahore"
                android:ems="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:id="@+id/citytxt" >
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_65sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="Address :"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:ems="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#0E9CE0"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:id="@+id/provnceedit" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="h#10 stret no 17 sabzar lahore"
                android:ems="30"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:id="@+id/addrestxt" >
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>










        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_170sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uploadbtn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_140sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/yelowbtn"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Stage 2"
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <!--
    </LinearLayout>-->
```

adapter

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.offlinemap.R;
import com.offlinemap.form.FormStage2;
import com.offlinemap.form.FormToUpdateData;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Stage2RecyclerViewAdapterViewCompleteList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Stage2RecyclerViewAdapterViewCompleteList.SearchViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<ModeClassCompleteListStage2> searcList;
    View thumb1View;
    private String jobid;
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;
    private modelclascompletelist model;
    String job;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    //ImageView image;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String pos;
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    /*static final int ZOOM = 2;*/
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    String savedItemClicked,scholid,tehsilo ,distrcto ,province ,sgtsID ;
    SharedPreferences preferences;



    public Stage2RecyclerViewAdapterViewCompleteList(Context mCtx, List<ModeClassCompleteListStage2> searcList)
    {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.searcList = searcList;
    }


    @Override
    public Stage2RecyclerViewAdapterViewCompleteList.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carview_introcomplete, null);
        return new Stage2RecyclerViewAdapterViewCompleteList.SearchViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Stage2RecyclerViewAdapterViewCompleteList.SearchViewHolder holder, final int position)

    {
        final ModeClassCompleteListStage2 model = searcList.get(position);



        holder.adres.setText(model.getDetailsadres());
        holder.scholname.setText(model.getScholname());
        holder.district.setText(model.getDistrict());
        holder.city.setText(model.getTehsil());

       /* Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(model.getImage1())
                .into(holder.image);*/

        if(model.getStg_id().equals("0")){
            holder.edit.setText("Add");

        }
        else {

            holder.edit.setText("Update");
        }






        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                /* String mtoid = searcList.get(position).get();*/
                 scholid = searcList.get(position).getScholid();
                 tehsilo = searcList.get(position).getTehsil();
                 distrcto = searcList.get(position).getDistrict();
                 province = searcList.get(position).getProvince();
                 sgtsID = searcList.get(position).getStg_id();
                 preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("scholid", scholid);
                editor.putString("thsillo", tehsilo);
                editor.putString("distrctto", distrcto);
                editor.putString("prov", province);
                editor.putString("sgts",sgtsID);
                editor.apply();

                if(holder.edit.getText().toString().equals("Add")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx.getApplicationContext(), FormStage2.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    mCtx.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx.getApplicationContext(), FormToUpdateData.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    mCtx.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                }


            }


        });




    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        /*if (searcList.size() == 0) {
            .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }*/
        return searcList.size();
    }

    class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        /*TextView movingitem, pickup, dropoff,currentbid,date,edit,delete,acceptbid,message,invitetransport,viewquote,similarjob,mesagecount,simlarcount;
        ImageView image,largeimage,editimage;
        CardView cardView;
        ImageView delicon,similaricon,inviteicon,mainimageicon,mesageicon;*/
        TextView adres, city, scholname, principalname, secondpersonname, entryno,district;
        Button edit;


        public SearchViewHolder(View itemView)

        {
            super(itemView);


            adres = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addrestxt);
            scholname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.scholnametxt);
            edit= itemView.findViewById(R.id.uploadbtn);
            district = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tehsilname);
            city = itemView.findViewById(R.id.citytxt);
          /*  movingitem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.MovingItemServlivep);
            pickup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pickupservlivep);
            dropoff = itemView.findViewById(R.id.DropOffServlivep);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagecardlivep);
            currentbid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.BidServlivep);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateservlivep);
            edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editjob);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deletejob);
            //   similarjob = itemView.findViewById(R.id.similarjobtext);
            acceptbid  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.biddetailslivep);
            viewquote  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offerpricelivep);
            //  invitetransport = itemView.findViewById(R.id.invitetransportertext);
            mesagecount  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countermsgs);
            // simlarcount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countersimlar);
            editimage= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView98);

            mesageicon= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagy98);

            delicon= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagy971);

            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.markeListCard);

            //  similaricon= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagy981);

            // inviteicon= itemView.findViewById(R.id.ima98);

            mainimageicon= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagecardlivep);*/
        }


    /*    public void setFilter(List<UserInfo> newList){
            data=new ArrayList<>();
            data.addAll(newList);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }*/

    }




}
```

Comment: How are you loading item inside Recycler View?

Comment: It would help if you would post the XML where the `RecyclerView` is defined.

Comment: iam loading it from server through FastAndroidNetworking library @GianlucaBenucci

Comment: in that xml there is just a recyclerview ..nothing much .. @Cheticamp

Comment: And once you get the response you load the items with an AsyncTask or Thread? Or all together?

Comment: all together @GianlucaBenucci

Comment: Well in this case you've to use an AsyncTask for load first set of data and when you reach a number of element you can load more element.